# Bad Performance With Games Under Wine

Tags: 12.04, ati, wine

I'm somewhat new to Linux. I've dabbled with it before but never more than just experimentation in a VM or dual boot where I almost always reverted back to Windows soon after (more due to a lack of commitment than a dislike for the OS).

Anyway my problem is that in the two games (Guild Wars and Team Fortress 2) I've tried so far I get fairly bad performance. Despite both games having a "Platinum" rating I've still been forced to run both in DirectX 8, otherwise they either crash, have texture defects or the UI is missing. By "bad performance" I mean sub-30 FPS where there are some players and regular large framerate drops with video settings on low.

Currently in my mind I believe the performance issues are just a problem with the drivers because my graphics card is a AMD 7850 which is virtually brand new and probably not properly supported yet but I'm unsure and would appreciate advice or tips to improve things.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and I am usually logged in a Gnome Classic session. I have installed AMD's proprietary drivers (Catalyst version 12.4) and have Wine 1.4 installed. I have used Winetricks to install DX9/DX10 dlls and other things.

Comment: Video drivers not supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those that have stumbled on this post, my issue ended up being some form of fault with Compiz.

If Compiz was running, performance was greatly reduced in 3D applications such as games. My solution was just to change window manager/desktop environment. I discovered this with the help of TechZilla in a seperate post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136054/bad-3d-performance-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as Ubuntu 12.04 is fairly new things are not quite optimized yet, but it's on its way. And wine is not known for having the greatest amount of performance, sadly. : ( But just wait, I've got a feeling that gaming is soon coming to Linux as well as on the other operating systems; Valve is even working on a Steam version for Linux and EA made some (free :D ) (shitty) games for free. So we can expect more gaming content in future versions, I suppose. But have you even installed a driver? I got integrated graphics in my Intel Pentium Dual core from 2008, and it runs decent on lowest settings with the free Nvidia drivers : /

Comment: As I said I have the latest proprietary drivers for AMD installed. I understand there would be a performance hit or incompatibilities with Wine, but I was expecting things to at least be playable for 8 year old games on a modern graphics card. ;)

I just mainly wanted help to determine the main cause for the bad performance (Gnome? Wine?) or if I should blame it on my new graphics card that likely isn't properly supported yet. Or if there's some sort of easy solution/trick that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with Team Fortress Two, however with Guild Wars, your on your own. Just because Team Fortress Two is on low video quality, does it mean that there aren't other things making you lag. Unless you have a bad problem with screen tearing (Two screens at the same time.) turn off V-sensitivity because V-sensitivity intentionally make the game lag to stop screen tearing, and disable mouse acceleration because you don't need a faster mouse. It should stop lagging too badly.