# Abysmal 3D performance in Wine with ATI HD6950 under 12.04

Tags: ati, wine, games

Running Vanilla WoW in both Wine 1.4 and through PlayOnLinux which is using Wine 1.2.1 and performance is completely unacceptable.  3D is working fine in native Linux titles such as Bastion.

Here's what things look like with OpenGL (there's a lot of graphical corruption in terms of objects flickering, also there appears to be a log or something wedged in my character, this screenshot doesn't do a good job of showing it off):

[image]

And here's things with DirectX 9:

[image]

I have the Ubuntu provided ATI drivers on a HD6950, and I don't know why things are so bad.  The game runs at vsync at 1920x1080 at max settings with AA in 3D on Windows without a problem.  Oh, and 64-bit if that changes anything.

```
    ruscour@ruscour-desktop:~$ glxgears
    6996 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1399.169 FPS
    7548 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1509.521 FPS
    ruscour@ruscour-desktop:~$ fgl_glxgears
    Using GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
    2875 frames in 5.0 seconds = 575.000 FPS
    2906 frames in 5.0 seconds = 581.200 FPS
```

That's in Unity 3D, haven't messed too much with anything so compositing probably enabled if it's on by default.

Various diagnostics:

[lspci -v](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1074298/)

ruscour@ruscour-desktop:~$ lspci -v

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited Device 186b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 54
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fe8e0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fe8c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
    Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon
```

[fglrxinfo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1074300/)

```
ruscour@ruscour-desktop:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11627 Compatibility Profile Context
```

[xvinfo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1074302/)

```
ruscour@ruscour-desktop:~$ xvinfo
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
  Adaptor #0: "AMD Radeon AVIVO Video"
    number of ports: 4
    port base: 143
    operations supported: PutImage 
    supported visuals:
      depth 24, visualID 0x23
      depth 24, visualID 0x24
      depth 24, visualID 0x25
      depth 24, visualID 0x26
      depth 24, visualID 0x27
      depth 24, visualID 0x28
      depth 24, visualID 0x29
      depth 24, visualID 0x2a
      depth 24, visualID 0x2b
      depth 24, visualID 0x2c
      depth 24, visualID 0x2d
      depth 24, visualID 0x2e
      depth 24, visualID 0x2f
      depth 24, visualID 0x30
      depth 24, visualID 0x31
      depth 24, visualID 0x32
      depth 24, visualID 0x33
      depth 24, visualID 0x34
      depth 24, visualID 0x35
      depth 24, visualID 0x36
      depth 24, visualID 0x37
      depth 24, visualID 0x38
      depth 24, visualID 0x39
      depth 24, visualID 0x3a
      depth 24, visualID 0x3b
      depth 24, visualID 0x3c
      depth 24, visualID 0x3d
      depth 24, visualID 0x3e
      depth 24, visualID 0x3f
      depth 24, visualID 0x40
      depth 24, visualID 0x41
      depth 24, visualID 0x42
      depth 24, visualID 0x43
      depth 24, visualID 0x44
      depth 24, visualID 0x45
      depth 24, visualID 0x46
      depth 24, visualID 0x47
      depth 24, visualID 0x48
      depth 24, visualID 0x49
      depth 24, visualID 0x4a
      depth 24, visualID 0x4b
      depth 24, visualID 0x4c
      depth 24, visualID 0x4d
      depth 24, visualID 0x4e
      depth 24, visualID 0x4f
      depth 24, visualID 0x50
      depth 24, visualID 0x51
      depth 24, visualID 0x52
      depth 24, visualID 0x53
      depth 24, visualID 0x54
      depth 24, visualID 0x55
      depth 24, visualID 0x56
      depth 24, visualID 0x57
      depth 24, visualID 0x58
      depth 24, visualID 0x59
      depth 24, visualID 0x5a
      depth 24, visualID 0x5b
      depth 24, visualID 0x5c
      depth 24, visualID 0x5d
      depth 24, visualID 0x5e
      depth 24, visualID 0x5f
      depth 24, visualID 0x60
      depth 24, visualID 0x61
      depth 24, visualID 0x62
      depth 24, visualID 0x63
      depth 24, visualID 0x64
      depth 24, visualID 0x65
      depth 24, visualID 0x66
      depth 24, visualID 0x67
      depth 24, visualID 0x68
      depth 24, visualID 0x69
      depth 24, visualID 0x6a
      depth 24, visualID 0x6b
      depth 24, visualID 0x6c
      depth 24, visualID 0x6d
      depth 24, visualID 0x6e
      depth 24, visualID 0x6f
      depth 24, visualID 0x70
      depth 24, visualID 0x71
      depth 24, visualID 0x72
    number of attributes: 10
      "XV_SET_DEFAULTS" (range 0 to 1)
              client settable attribute
      "XV_DOUBLE_BUFFER" (range 0 to 1)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 1)
      "XV_BRIGHTNESS" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_CONTRAST" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_SATURATION" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_COLOR" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_HUE" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_RED_INTENSITY" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_GREEN_INTENSITY" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
      "XV_BLUE_INTENSITY" (range -1000 to 1000)
              client settable attribute
              client gettable attribute (current value is 0)
    maximum XvImage size: 4096 x 4096
    Number of image formats: 4
      id: 0x32315659 (YV12)
        guid: 59563132-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 12
        number of planes: 3
        type: YUV (planar)
      id: 0x30323449 (I420)
        guid: 49343230-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 12
        number of planes: 3
        type: YUV (planar)
      id: 0x32595559 (YUY2)
        guid: 59555932-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 16
        number of planes: 1
        type: YUV (packed)
      id: 0x59565955 (UYVY)
        guid: 55595659-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
        bits per pixel: 16
        number of planes: 1
        type: YUV (packed)
```

---

```
glxinfo | grep rendering returns Yes.
```

If anything else is needed to help me out, just ask and I'll post it.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, like there's some 32-bit GL library I don't have or something like that, but I'm stuck so hopefully someone can give me a hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad Performance With Games Under Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134503/bad-performance-with-games-under-wine)

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing Dlls in Directx9 , other than that don't really know.
I too have a HD6950 2GB , it has sucky performance in ubuntu.
If you ever solve it let me know...