# I have installed Catalyst, but my GPU is not used (HD 7970M)

Tags: ati, graphics, opengl

I have installed AMD Catalyst, but when I am playing something, then it is not using my GPU (in this case Garry's Mod).

My output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` is

`OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7970M
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.12798 Core Profile Context 13.35.1005
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.3.12798 Compatibility Profile Context 13.35.1005
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:`

I can tell its not using the GPU because my CPU is as hot as hell, but my GPU is completely cold.

This is the information screen on my catalyst: http://screencloud.net/v/ebxD

Comment: It is using the GPU - the evidence is right there *"OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7970M"*. If it were using your CPU you would see something like *"OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile"* (obviously the exact text would be different for other CPUs)

Comment: I get that, but it is quite obviously not utilising it. Either it uses it not even close to its full potential, or not at all.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of the drivers? It is probably a bug in the Catalyst driver, try  update to the latest (14.4 stable / 14.6 beta), and if still broken file a bug with AMD. I found [this report](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=492&threadid=172410) of poor performance with HD7970M under Windows, and a report of [terrible performance under Linux](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160265), and [another](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864957182847070880/)... so it seems AMD have problems with this specific card.

Comment: You could always try the open source drivers.

Comment: I am scared of making the switch now, because I don't want my display drivers suddenly just completely dying. Anyone has any good links to how to switch from closed to open source drivers?

Comment: Follow instructions for "Removing (purging) existing drivers" at [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) Assuming you are using Ubuntu 14.04, the open source drivers should be already installed.

Comment: I deleted all fglrx drivers. Native applications run fine now, but anything running from wine is using only CPU.

Comment: Wine should be using GPU but some things don't perform so well in Wine, due to Direct3D being translated to OpenGL, or compositing causing a performance hit (see [Bad Performance With Games Under Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134503/bad-performance-with-games-under-wine)). Are you otherwise happy with the open source driver (we can close this question)?

Comment: Good. I wrote up the summary answer, please accept it to help others find this answer to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU is being used - the evidence is glxinfo output line *"OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7970M"*. If it were using your CPU you would see something like *"OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile"* (obviously the exact text would be different for other CPUs).

Your performance problems seem to be caused by poor support by AMD proprietary Catalyst drivers for HD7970. I found [this report](http://forums.amd.com/game/messageview.cfm?catid=492&threadid=172410) of poor performance with HD7970M under Windows, and a report of [terrible performance](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160265) under Linux, and [another](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864957182847070880/)... so it seems AMD have problems with this specific card.

To workaround this issue you can switch to the open source drivers by following instructions for "Removing (purging) existing drivers" at [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) Assuming you are using Ubuntu 14.04, the open source drivers will already be installed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open amdcccle(admin)
2. Enter Your Password
3. Go to Switchable Graphics
4. Select High Performance GPU for optimal graphics performance.
5. Press OK and reboot

Best of Luck

Comment: I have already switched to GPU, that did not fix it.